# I found a tag synonym

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

The [toward](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toward) and [towards](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/towards) tags are synonyms. They mean the same thing, and basically are the same thing.

Comment: Moreover, each is used exactly once, on the same question. It seems pretty useless, unless it's a stop word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As StoneyB's comment points out:

> each is used exactly once, on the same question. It seems pretty useless

I retagged the question and both tags are now gone.  Problem solved!